# Calculate the number of html element with js

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple div elements with same id='mydiv'.I want to calculate these divs and Iam using the code

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').length
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work as `getElementById` will always return an element with the specified ID and null if the specified ID doesn't exist

From [ECMA](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/ecma-script-language-binding.html)

```
 getElementById(elementId) This method returns a Element. The elementId
    parameter is of type DOMString.
```

What you can do is to assign each div with class

```
<div class="mydiv"></div>
<div class="mydiv"></div>
<div class="mydiv"></div>
<div class="mydiv"></div>
<div class="mydiv"></div>​​​​​​​​​
```

And iterate over:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if(divs[i].className == 'mydiv') count++;
}

alert(count);
```

If your clients support `document.getElementsByClassName()`, it's even more concise:

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('mydiv').length)
```

Comment: Well, not **always**. If it can't find a matching element, it returns `null`. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

What you should do is use class instead of ID's. ID is for one element only, class is for multiple.

http://jsfiddle.net/d7AHV/

Answer (score 0):

You've been told about multiple elements with the same ID, but in rare cases it might be unavoidable (e.g. an XML document over which you have no control). The only adverse behaviour is that selecting by ID will usually only return the first one (but that's not guaranteed).

You can count elements with the same id by looping over all the elements in the document and counting the ones with a matching id, e.g.

```
function countSameIds(id) {
  var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i=allNodes.length, count=0; i; ) {
    if (allNodes[--i].id == id) {
      ++count;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```